# What the name of this houseplant

Tags: houseplants

[image]

Red stem
Red veins
Green Oval Leaves with Red outline

Answer (score 1):

Possibly Philodendron cv. ‘Red Wings’.

Looks to be young plant.

Note that Philodendron plants and their leaves in particular change form to varying degrees as they age and change colour depending on how much light/sunlight they are exposed to.